# How to pass serilized binary data via post request

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

Consider you want to communicate with endpoint in a `post` request using `json` mimetype to pass parameters in the body of request.

One of the parameters to to pass in the `json` is `binary` more accurate `bytes` type data which lets assumes comes from `pickle.dumps`.

How can you create a valid `json` which will have this data passed to the endpoint, then will `unpickle` the binary data back from probably some sort of `string` back to `binary` data and then `pickle.loads` back to the object type itself?

Please specify a simple example to demonstrate

Comment: more precisely which kind of binary data you are referring?? image or generalize any data?

Comment: @Gahan: assume any data

Comment: so one way is that you can encode your pickled data into base64 and decode it afterward which works for both POST method as well as the GET method

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode the binary data in a text format that JSON can work with. The standard way to this is base64-encoding, which is available in the python standard library:

Encoding:

```
import base64

serialized_data = ... # this is the binary data to send
serialized_data_b64 = base64.b64encode(payload)
```

Decoding:

```
import base64

serialized_data_b64 = ... # this is the received data
serialized_data = base64.b64decode(serialized_data_b64)
```

If the data you send is very large, you may want to use base-85 encoding instead, which will make the encoded payload slightly smaller. However, it is less supported in other languages. For more info, see the [Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/base64.html)

Use `base64.b85encode` and `base64.b85decode` for the base-85 codec